# how to write a script output in a post in the act of creation of these posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming, addition

Hello community WordPress forum.
I have a need to write the posts the output of a function, but all to getting to do is to display real-time and run this script / function in all posts, with I do to write the posts the output of a function instead of display it in posts?
because what 's happening is that the script is running on all posts, and each refresh / access the pages, a new script number is generated! I would like the generator create a different number for each post, but write to output them, and not display a number to each new access.

```
// Declare the function
function gen_num()
{
// DETERMINE THE CHARACTER THAT CONTAIN THE PASSWORD
$caracteres = "012345678910111213141516171819";
// Shuffles THE CHARACTER AND HANDLE ONLY THE FIRST 10
$mistura = substr(str_shuffle($caracteres),0,10);
// DISPLAYS THE OUTCOME
print $mistura;
}

// Add custom post content, inject function in content.
function add_post_content($content) {
gen_num();
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_post_content');
```

see in herculestest.tk, browse the pages, make f5 to refresh.

Thank you very much.

==========================================
another attempt:

I created a custom field from ACF plugin named: numeration:

```
function gen_num()
{
global $post;
$mistura = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'numeration', true );

if ( '' == $mistura ) {
   //DETERMINE THE CHARACTER THAT CONTAIN THE PASSWORD
  $caracteres = "012345678910111213141516171819";
  // Shuffles THE CHARACTER AND HANDLE ONLY THE FIRST 10
  $mistura = substr(str_shuffle($caracteres),0,10);
  update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'numeration', $mistura );
}
 //DISPLAYS THE OUTCOME
print $mistura;
}

// Add custom post content, inject function in content.
function add_post_content($content) {
gen_num();
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_post_content');
```

---

this solution to not change the number each new access, now writing these data permanently in the database ?? because're not recording! if I change my theme, all the numbers in all the posts disappear, and if I make any errors in functions, php, these add up numbers, because they depend on the function running at him display the values, and worst of all, to fix the functions.php, the script will return to run and therefore, will be a re-run, which means that it will generate new numbers on all posts !! and this can not happen, should I ever have the same values!

Comment: May someone please? I'm wanting this script is loaded automatically when creating a new post and I want him inject, write the output to a post of the field, that it put written truth in the post, see, herculestest.tk/admin herculetest herculeSTest1 acecem the contade to see in content-single.php and functions.php look for yves and see my attempt, and browse the pages stop test my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Post ID is unique in WordPress, is that number adequate for your needs?

Otherwise you'd need to generate a unique ID when the post is published and save it in a custom field. (Instead of your `gener_numb` function look into `uniqid`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php.)

Comment: So I had this idea of the value is written in a custom field, used the ACF plugin to create the field, but do not know the function to inject the result gener_numb within that field. I want every new post created, he writes these random number within the field, to be displayed in posts, how I do it?

I created a field with insert_content name and wrote in my single.php theme so that all that is written in the field, is displaying the posts. but how to make that injection of the values generated by gener_numb function I created for this insert_content custom field.

Comment: And on this last post code on the ID, the_ID forget or understand these issues in wordpres ID, got it in a manual and did not understand anything, considete to part .......this is automatic as this is but so what is written in the post by the function will never be changed. thanks.

Comment: doing what I wrote above, in my topic, I can display the result of script in every post, but not with it to be written in a form field that it is changed with each new access posts, each post is generated a number random different, here with you, but I can not have it written so as if I had written by hand in the post, for he it and not change, each post with your number but not ever change. for I am showing the execution of Script and not writing the result of it in the post, it must be written.

Comment: You'll have to write some code for this, whether you're using ACF or just creating the field yourself. For ACF see this tutorial (this tutorial is for a select field, your version will be simpler because you'll use a text field): http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/dynamically-populate-a-select-fields-choices/

Comment: And if I do not use custom field is simpler? could even enter the value generated within the the_content post? because I do not care about anything else besides inserting this result in the posts. no matter what method. I just want the result of this script is written in all posts. no matter the method since it is automated.

Comment: Whatever way you choose you'd have to hook your number generating function into something like `save_post`...

Comment: You can try this in single.php where you want to output the number: `<?php echo md5(get_the_ID()); ?>`

Comment: I just register a domain and host on a free server are low quality to be able to show what I'm trying to do:
herculestest.tk navigate the menu and realize that each shipment the function is executed within the posts, instead of writing the post the number permanently, see in practice what is happening.

access herculestest.tk/admin herculestest herculeSTest1

search by your browser the word: 'yves' in functions.php and single.php in appearence ==> editor, access the files on the right side.

you will see my job I need it in functions.php, la ta all ok
and see my failed attempt in single.php.

Comment: thank you for teaching this md5, I do not know but need to know self inject, write the values ​​generated by the function shown in all posts in the act of creating these posts

Comment: You' will need to save the generated value in a custom field associated with the post.

Comment: I created a custom field from ACF plugin names description: